# Stuck on stored procedure and cursor

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, signals, cursors

I'm trying to create a stored procedure that will accept a TYPEID  & user number as arguments then search for an available entry that has not been
taken/has been returned (shown comparing and looking through tables 1 and 2) and then inserts a new row in the loan table. Before then checking 
if the user is banned(table 3, Thinking using SIGNAL).

THE DATA:

```
TABLE1: 
+-----------+----------+
|    CODE   |  TYPEID  |
+-----------+----------+
| 441       |  mn014   |
| 223       |  mn014   |
| 224       |  mn014   |
| 655       |  mn089   |
| 854       |  mn089   |
| 449       |  mn032   |
+-----------+----------+

TABLE2:
+-----------+----------+----------+
| CODE      | TAKENDTE | RTURNDTE |
+-----------+----------+----------+
| 441       | 25/08/14 | 01/01/15 |
| 223       | 25/08/14 | 03/01/15 |
| 223       | 25/08/14 | 01/02/15 |
| 223       | 25/08/14 |   NULL   |
| 655       | 25/08/14 | 07/01/15 |
| 854       | 25/08/14 |   NULL   |
| 449       | 25/08/14 | 06/01/15 |
+-----------+---------------------+

TABLE3:
+-----------+----------+----------+
| USERNO    |   NAME   |  BANNED  |
+-----------+----------+----------+
| 111       |  Bob     |    0     |
| 112       |  Sally   |    1     |
| 113       |  Jim     |    0     |
| 114       |  Billy   |    0     |
| 115       |  Jessica |    0     |
| 116       |  Fred    |    0     |
| 117       |  Patrik  |    0     |
+-----------+---------------------+
```

I've tried using a CURSOR which is what  think i need to use but am getting errors i can't resolve this is what i've done so far

```
    DELIMITER $$

    CREATE PROCEDURE new_entry(IN isbn_search CHAR(17), useNO INT)

     BEGIN
     DECLARE complete BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE;
     DECLARE newEntry VARCHAR (30) DEFAULT ' ';
     DECLARE S CURSOR FOR
    select t1.*
    from table1 t1
    where typeid = 'mn014' and
          not exists (select 1
                      from table2 t2
                      where t2.code = t.code and
                            t2.rturndte is null
                     );      
     DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND
       SET complete = TRUE;

                OPEN S;
        SET newLoan = ' ';
        sloop : LOOP
        FETCH NEXT INTO newLoan;

        IF complete THEN 

       LEAVE sloop;

        END IF;

        SET newLoan = CONCAT (code, isbn, duration);


        CLOSE S;

END$$                
DELIMITER ;
```

any idea?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite understand what you need to do, but I see some problems that I list below:

- When you declare a cursor can't use `t1. *`, you must use the particular column, i.e.: `t1.CODE`
- The variable `newLoan` is not declared, must declare it before it can be assigned.
- The `LOOP` has no end (`END LOOP`).
- Variables `code`, `isbn` and `duration` of where you get?

Example:

```sql
DELIMITER $$

-- CREATE PROCEDURE `new_entry`(IN `isbn_search` CHAR(17), `useNO` INT)
CREATE PROCEDURE `new_entry`(`isbn_search` CHAR(17), `useNO` INT)
BEGIN
    -- DECLARE `complete` BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE `complete` BOOL DEFAULT FALSE;
    -- DECLARE `newEntry` VARCHAR (30) DEFAULT ' ';
    DECLARE `newLoan` VARCHAR (30) DEFAULT '';
    DECLARE `CONCAT_newLoan` VARCHAR (60) DEFAULT '';

    /*
    DECLARE S CURSOR FOR
        select t1.*
        from table1 t1
        where typeid = 'mn014' and
          not exists (select 1
                      from table2 t2
                      where t2.code = t.code and
                            t2.rturndte is null
                     );
    */

    /* Simplified statement */
    DECLARE `S` CURSOR FOR
    SELECT `t1`.`CODE`
    FROM `table1` `t1`
    WHERE `TYPEID` = 'mn014';
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET `complete` := TRUE;
    OPEN `S`;

    -- SET newLoan = ' ';

    `sloop`: LOOP
        FETCH `S` INTO `newLoan`;
        IF `complete` THEN
            CLOSE `S`;
            LEAVE `sloop`;
        END IF;
        -- SET `newLoan` = CONCAT(`code`, `isbn`, `duration`);
        /* Simplified statement */
        SET `CONCAT_newLoan` := CONCAT(`CONCAT_newLoan`, `newLoan`);
    END LOOP;
    -- CLOSE S;
    SELECT `CONCAT_newLoan`;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/42ca0/1)</kbd>